# Как представить кривую Безье через окружность?

Tags: математика, графика

Кривая Безье задана 3 точками: P0, P1, P2. Как найти уравнение окружности, которая будет максимально приближена к кривой Безье? 
Возможно ли это сделать? Или обязательно требуются дополнительные условия?

Comment: А что означает «максимально приближена»?

Comment: тоже задался вопросом. Если кривая Безье задана 3 точками, тогда форма кривой будет парабола, от положения средней точки будет зависеть высота и наклон. Конкретизируйте, что значит приблизить окружность к параболе.